# Access violation writing location for passing value

Tags: c++

I'm trying to pass value from Level class to Grid class and access violation happened in grid_w and grid_h.
I have tried using extern but it say that `invalid storage class for a class member`. And I tried to use `Grid a; a.setgrid(5);` but it can not pass the value.
Anyone could explain it to me?

Level.cpp

```
#include "Level.h"
#include "Grid.h"

USING_NS_CC;

using namespace CocosDenshion;

Grid* layer25;

CCScene* Level::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();
    Level *layer = Level::create();

    layer25 = Grid::create();
    layer25->retain();

    scene->addChild(layer);
    scene->addChild(layer25);

    return scene;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool Level::init()
{
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        setTouchEnabled(true);
    }

    Grid pass;
    pass.setgrid(5); // send value here, retreive in Grid.h


    return true;
}
```

Level.h

```
#ifndef __LEVEL_H__
#define __LEVEL_H__

#include "cocos2d.h"
using namespace cocos2d;


class Grid;

class Level : public cocos2d::CCLayer
{

public:
    virtual bool init();  
    static cocos2d::CCScene* scene();
    CREATE_FUNC(Level);
};

#endif // __HELLOWORLD_SCENE_H__
```

Grid.cpp

```
#include "Grid.h"

using namespace CocosDenshion;

USING_NS_CC;

CCLayer* Grid::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    OnetGrid *layer2 = OnetGrid::create();

    scene->addChild(layer2);

    return layer2;
}

// on "init" you need to initialize your instance
bool Grid::init()
{
    if ( !CCLayer::init() )
    {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        setTouchEnabled(true);
    }

    grid();

    return true;
}

void Grid::grid()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    cakes = CCArray::createWithCapacity(grid_w*grid_h);
    cakes->retain();
    CCSize visibleSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();
    CCPoint origin = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleOrigin();

    if (grid_w == 10 && grid_h == 12) {
        int x = 51.5 * grid_w/2;
        int y = 55 * grid_h/2;
        int random[120];
        int rnd;
        int rnd2;
        srand (time(NULL));
        for (int l = 0; l < 60; l++) {
            rnd = rand()%20 + 1;
            rnd2 = rnd;
            random[l] = rnd;
            random[l+60] = rnd2;
        }
        int l = 0;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < grid_h; j++) {
            for ( int k = 0; k < grid_w; k++) {
                CCLabelTTF* tests = CCLabelTTF::create("Done", "Life is goofy", 60);
                tests->setColor(ccc3(0, 0, 0));
                tests->setPosition(ccp(400, 400));
                this->addChild(tests, 5);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // but being executed in here
        char text[256];
        sprintf (text, "%d, %d", grid_h, grid_w);
        CCLabelTTF* tests_ = CCLabelTTF::create(text, "Life is goofy", 60);
        test_->setColor(ccc3(0, 0, 0));
        test_->setPosition(ccp(400, 400));
        this->addChild(test_, 5);
    }
}
```

Grid.h

```
#ifndef _GRID_H_
#define _GRID_H_

#include "cocos2d.h"

USING_NS_CC;
using namespace cocos2d;

class Grid : public CCLayer
{
public:
    int grid_w;
    int grid_h;

    virtual bool init();
    void setgrid(int a) //retreive in here, print in Grid.cpp
    {
        switch (a){
        case 1:
            grid_w = 6;
            grid_h = 6;
            break;
        case 2:
            grid_w = 6;
            grid_h = 9;
            break;
        case 3:
            grid_w = 8;
            grid_h = 9;
            break;
        case 4:
            grid_w = 9;
            grid_h = 10;
            break;
        case 5:
            grid_w = 10;
            grid_h = 12;
            break;
        default:
            grid_w = 10;
            grid_h = 12;
            break;
        }

    }
   int getgrid_w() {
        return grid_w;
    }

    int getgrid_h() {
        return grid_h;
    }

    static cocos2d::CCLayer* scene();
    void grid();

    CREATE_FUNC(Grid);
};

#endif
```

Comment: `pass` is not initialized.  `Grid a; a.setgrid(5);` should be fine.  Perhaps you could show us a complete example that was causing the issue?

Comment: `Grid a; a.setgrid(5);` would be better. If you are having trouble with that approach then describe in more detail what trouble you are having.

Comment: @MattMcNabb it can't retreive the value. grid_w will be -8421 and grid_h will be -8421

Comment: This is why a complete example is important.  [This works fine](http://ideone.com/0ob0H8).  You should read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As said, the second line is not valid until you have a pass object.

Comment: @nylon reduce your code to a small example that shows the problem and then include it in the question. Nobody is going to download zip files from dropbox

Comment: In the `Level::init` function, `Grid pass;` declares a local variable.  It will exist only until the end of that function so you won't be able to access it later.  You probably want to make it a member variable in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer. `Level *layer = Level::create();` is calling for `Level::init()` first, so when executing  `Grid pass; pass.setgrid(5);` it returned to `Undefined behavior` because Grid layer have not allocated any memory.

What I do is moving `Level *layer = Level::create();` after create Grid layer:

```
CCScene* Level::scene()
{
    CCScene *scene = CCScene::create();

    layer25 = Grid::create();
    layer25->retain();

    Level *layer = Level::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    scene->addChild(layer25);

    return scene;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a pointer named `pass` to an object but have not allocated any memory for it. The pointer `pass` can contain any random value, which may or may not be a valid address.
Accessing memory from unallocated locations is `Undefined behavior`.

So you need to allocate memory using `new`, like this :

```
Grid* pass = new Grid;
```

This allocates memory for the object in the free store so that you can access the data members. Remember to free the memory once you're done.

You can also store the object on contiguous memory like this :

```
Grid gr_obj;
Grid* pass = &gr_obj;
```

Answer (score 0):

How can it work without allocating memory for the pointer `pass`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized `pass`. So, it is undefined behaviour to call methods with uninitialized pointer.

You need something like:

`pass = new Grid();`

Comment: it can't retreive the value :(